# Generating Registration Password results in 404 error

Tags: passwords, http-status-code-404, bots, registration, channel

Using the Bot Channels Registration created a Bot app, was provisioned successfully. I require the App ID and the Pwd so navigated to the Bot Resource , clicked on settings and then Manage next tp the App ID and gives ,me the following error.

Following the help on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 
Get Registration Password - Step 4 results in the error. any help much appreciated.

[error 404 on clicking Manage App Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbwpl.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by two steps :
1.  When you click on manage, just add “/true” in the end of the URL that is opened and you will be able to access the page
2.  Alternatively you can go to Azure active directory and click on app registration, then search  in the personal account with your client ID/ Application id you will be able to access the page

Reason :
this issue happens because the bot is created using personal account, so when we click on Manage button the flow go and search the app registered from owned account. We can make use of above workarounds.